# How can i center an inner div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am really don't where is the problem of this.I am trying this with `margin:0 auto` for `center` a `div`.But i have failed again and again.Could anyone one solve my problem? I have searched and found some solution in **stackoverflow** but those answer do not satisfy my situation.I want two price table in the center of div with `float:left` each other. By the way i am also using twitter bootstrap.

**[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/d8mqnrhf/1/)**

Thanks in advanced.

```css
.wrapper {
  background-color: #05588B;
}
.pricing_main {
  padding: 10px;
}
.btn1 {
  background: #008ED6;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #008ED6, #008ED6);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #008ED6, #008ED6);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #008ED6, #008ED6);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #008ED6, #008ED6);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #008ED6, #008ED6);
  -webkit-border-radius: 2;
  -moz-border-radius: 2;
  border-radius: 2px;
  font-family: Arial;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 20px 15px 20px 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: 1px solid #008ED6;
  margin-right: 2%;
  margin-bottom: 4%;
}
.btn1:hover {
  background: #3cb0fd;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 1px solid #008ED6;
}
.button_area {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 2%;
}
.btn2 {
  background: #055689;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #055689, #055689);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #055689, #055689);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #055689, #055689);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #055689, #055689);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #055689, #055689);
  -webkit-border-radius: 2;
  -moz-border-radius: 2;
  border-radius: 2px;
  font-family: Arial;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 20px 30px 20px 30px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: 1px solid #ffffff;
}
.btn2:hover {
  background: #008ED6;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #008ED6, #008ED6);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #008ED6, #008ED6);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #008ED6, #008ED6);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #008ED6, #008ED6);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #008ED6, #008ED6);
  text-decoration: none;
}
.button_group {
  padding-bottom: 3%;
}
.price_block {
  width: 37%!important;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-right: 6%;
  padding-left: 0px!important;
  padding-right: 0px!important;
}
.price_block2 {
  width: 37%!important;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding-left: 0px!important;
  padding-right: 0px!important;
}
.price_block h3 {
  text-align: center;
  color: #008ED6;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.price_block2 h3 {
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.price {
  background-color: #008ED6;
  color: white;
}
.price2 {
  background-color: #E5E5E5;
  color: black;
}
.price_block .price {
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 0px;
  padding: 18px;
}
.price_block2 .price2 {
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 0px;
  padding: 18px;
}
.price_block ul {
  margin-top: 7%;
  color: #909090
}
.price_block ul li {
  list-style: none;
  line-height: 30px;
}
.price_block2 ul {
  margin-top: 7%;
  color: #909090
}
.price_block2 ul li {
  list-style: none;
  line-height: 30px;
}
.price_block .btn3 {
  text-align: center;
}
.fa-check {
  background-color: #0DAA7A;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 8px;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  text-align: center;
}
.fa-close {
  background-color: #e74c3c;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 8px;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  text-align: center;
}
.btn3 {
  text-align: center;
}
.price_block .btn3 {
  text-align: center;
  background: #008ED6;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #008ED6, #008ED6);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #008ED6, #008ED6);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #008ED6, #008ED6);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #008ED6, #008ED6);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #008ED6, #008ED6);
  -webkit-border-radius: 2;
  -moz-border-radius: 2;
  border-radius: 2px;
  font-family: Arial;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 1px solid #008ED6;
  margin-top: 4%;
  margin-bottom: 4%;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.price_block .btn3:hover {
  background: #3da4e3;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3da4e3, #3da4e3);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3da4e3, #3da4e3);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #3da4e3, #3da4e3);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #3da4e3, #3da4e3);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3da4e3, #3da4e3);
  text-decoration: none;
}
.price_block2 .btn4 {
  text-align: center;
  background: #909090;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #909090, #909090);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #909090, #909090);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #909090, #909090);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #909090, #909090);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #909090, #909090);
  -webkit-border-radius: 2;
  -moz-border-radius: 2;
  border-radius: 2px;
  font-family: Arial;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 1px solid #909090;
  margin-top: 4%;
  margin-bottom: 4%;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.price_block2 .btn4:hover {
  background: #909090;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #909090, #909090);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #909090, #909090);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #909090, #909090);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #909090, #909090);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #909090, #909090);
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="pricing_main">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="price_wrap">
        <div class="col-xs-6 price_block">
          <h3>ANNUAL PLAN</h3>
          <div class="price">
            <p>Save 33% on the Annual Plan</p>
            <h1><strike>$37</strike> <span style="color:#FDBC37;font-weight:bold">$25</span></h1>
            <p>/billed annually</p>
          </div>
          <ul>
            <li><i class="fa fa-check"></i> Find Thousand of Profitable Keywords in Seconds</li>
            <li><i class="fa fa-check"></i> Calculate Keyword Competitiveness</li>
            <li><i class="fa fa-check"></i> Competitor analysis on Top 10 Google Results</li>
            <li><i class="fa fa-check"></i> Check Rankings of sites in Google, Yahoo, and Bing</li>
            <li><i class="fa fa-check"></i> Import Lists of 10,000 Keywords at Once</li>
            <li><i class="fa fa-check"></i> Get Access to the Platinum VIP Facebook Community</li>
            <li style="font-weight:bold"><i class="fa fa-check"></i> FREE Access to Long Tail University ($197 in Value)</li>
            <li style="font-weight:bold"><i class="fa fa-check"></i> Save 33% on Platinum with the Annual Plan</li>
          </ul>
          <center>
            <button type="button" class="btn3">ORDER NOW</button>
          </center>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 price_block2">
          <h3>MONTHLY PLAN</h3>
          <div class="price2">
            <p>Monthly Payment</p>
            <h1>$37</h1>
            <p>/billed monthly</p>
          </div>
          <ul>
            <li><i class="fa fa-check"></i> Find Thousand of Profitable Keywords in Seconds</li>
            <li><i class="fa fa-check"></i> Calculate Keyword Competitiveness</li>
            <li><i class="fa fa-check"></i> Competitor analysis on Top 10 Google Results</li>
            <li><i class="fa fa-check"></i> Check Rankings of sites in Google, Yahoo, and Bing</li>
            <li><i class="fa fa-check"></i> Import Lists of 10,000 Keywords at Once</li>
            <li><i class="fa fa-check"></i> Get Access to the Platinum VIP Facebook Community</li>
            <li style="font-weight:bold"><i class="fa fa-close"></i> FREE Access to Long Tail University ($197 in Value)</li>
            <li style="font-weight:bold"><i class="fa fa-close"></i> Save 33% on Platinum with the Annual Plan</li>
          </ul>
          <center>
            <button type="button" class="btn4">ORDER NOW</button>
          </center>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you want both div in one row, next to each other?

Comment: @Leothelion yes and center also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

added `display:inline-block` for `.price_block` and `.price_block2`.

And added `text-align:center` for `.price_wrap`

```css
.wrapper {
  background-color: #05588B;
}
.pricing_main {
  padding: 10px;
}
.btn1 {
  background: #008ED6;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #008ED6, #008ED6);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #008ED6, #008ED6);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #008ED6, #008ED6);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #008ED6, #008ED6);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #008ED6, #008ED6);
  -webkit-border-radius: 2;
  -moz-border-radius: 2;
  border-radius: 2px;
  font-family: Arial;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 20px 15px 20px 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: 1px solid #008ED6;
  margin-right: 2%;
  margin-bottom: 4%;
}
.btn1:hover {
  background: #3cb0fd;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 1px solid #008ED6;
}
.button_area {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 2%;
}
.btn2 {
  background: #055689;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #055689, #055689);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #055689, #055689);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #055689, #055689);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #055689, #055689);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #055689, #055689);
  -webkit-border-radius: 2;
  -moz-border-radius: 2;
  border-radius: 2px;
  font-family: Arial;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 20px 30px 20px 30px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: 1px solid #ffffff;
}
.btn2:hover {
  background: #008ED6;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #008ED6, #008ED6);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #008ED6, #008ED6);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #008ED6, #008ED6);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #008ED6, #008ED6);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #008ED6, #008ED6);
  text-decoration: none;
}
.button_group {
  padding-bottom: 3%;
}
.price_wrap{
  text-align: center;
}
.price_block {
  width: 37%!important;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-right: 6%;
  padding-left: 0px!important;
  padding-right: 0px!important;
  display: inline-block;
}
.price_block2 {
  width: 37%!important;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding-left: 0px!important;
  padding-right: 0px!important;
  display: inline-block;
}
.price_block h3 {
  text-align: center;
  color: #008ED6;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.price_block2 h3 {
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.price {
  background-color: #008ED6;
  color: white;
}
.price2 {
  background-color: #E5E5E5;
  color: black;
}
.price_block .price {
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 0px;
  padding: 18px;
}
.price_block2 .price2 {
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 0px;
  padding: 18px;
}
.price_block ul {
  margin-top: 7%;
  color: #909090
}
.price_block ul li {
  list-style: none;
  line-height: 30px;
}
.price_block2 ul {
  margin-top: 7%;
  color: #909090
}
.price_block2 ul li {
  list-style: none;
  line-height: 30px;
}
.price_block .btn3 {
  text-align: center;
}
.fa-check {
  background-color: #0DAA7A;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 8px;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  text-align: center;
}
.fa-close {
  background-color: #e74c3c;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 8px;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  text-align: center;
}
.btn3 {
  text-align: center;
}
.price_block .btn3 {
  text-align: center;
  background: #008ED6;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #008ED6, #008ED6);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #008ED6, #008ED6);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #008ED6, #008ED6);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #008ED6, #008ED6);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #008ED6, #008ED6);
  -webkit-border-radius: 2;
  -moz-border-radius: 2;
  border-radius: 2px;
  font-family: Arial;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 1px solid #008ED6;
  margin-top: 4%;
  margin-bottom: 4%;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.price_block .btn3:hover {
  background: #3da4e3;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3da4e3, #3da4e3);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3da4e3, #3da4e3);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #3da4e3, #3da4e3);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #3da4e3, #3da4e3);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3da4e3, #3da4e3);
  text-decoration: none;
}
.price_block2 .btn4 {
  text-align: center;
  background: #909090;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #909090, #909090);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #909090, #909090);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #909090, #909090);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #909090, #909090);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #909090, #909090);
  -webkit-border-radius: 2;
  -moz-border-radius: 2;
  border-radius: 2px;
  font-family: Arial;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 1px solid #909090;
  margin-top: 4%;
  margin-bottom: 4%;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.price_block2 .btn4:hover {
  background: #909090;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #909090, #909090);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #909090, #909090);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #909090, #909090);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #909090, #909090);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #909090, #909090);
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="pricing_main">
  <div class="container">
<div class="row">
  <div class="price_wrap">
    <div class="col-xs-6 price_block">
      <h3>ANNUAL PLAN</h3>
      <div class="price">
        <p>Save 33% on the Annual Plan</p>
        <h1><strike>$37</strike> <span style="color:#FDBC37;font-weight:bold">$25</span></h1>
        <p>/billed annually</p>
      </div>
      <ul>
        <li><i class="fa fa-check"></i> Find Thousand of Profitable Keywords in Seconds</li>
        <li><i class="fa fa-check"></i> Calculate Keyword Competitiveness</li>
        <li><i class="fa fa-check"></i> Competitor analysis on Top 10 Google Results</li>
        <li><i class="fa fa-check"></i> Check Rankings of sites in Google, Yahoo, and Bing</li>
        <li><i class="fa fa-check"></i> Import Lists of 10,000 Keywords at Once</li>
        <li><i class="fa fa-check"></i> Get Access to the Platinum VIP Facebook Community</li>
        <li style="font-weight:bold"><i class="fa fa-check"></i> FREE Access to Long Tail University ($197 in Value)</li>
        <li style="font-weight:bold"><i class="fa fa-check"></i> Save 33% on Platinum with the Annual Plan</li>
      </ul>
      <center>
        <button type="button" class="btn3">ORDER NOW</button>
      </center>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 price_block2">
      <h3>MONTHLY PLAN</h3>
      <div class="price2">
        <p>Monthly Payment</p>
        <h1>$37</h1>
        <p>/billed monthly</p>
      </div>
      <ul>
        <li><i class="fa fa-check"></i> Find Thousand of Profitable Keywords in Seconds</li>
        <li><i class="fa fa-check"></i> Calculate Keyword Competitiveness</li>
        <li><i class="fa fa-check"></i> Competitor analysis on Top 10 Google Results</li>
        <li><i class="fa fa-check"></i> Check Rankings of sites in Google, Yahoo, and Bing</li>
        <li><i class="fa fa-check"></i> Import Lists of 10,000 Keywords at Once</li>
        <li><i class="fa fa-check"></i> Get Access to the Platinum VIP Facebook Community</li>
        <li style="font-weight:bold"><i class="fa fa-close"></i> FREE Access to Long Tail University ($197 in Value)</li>
        <li style="font-weight:bold"><i class="fa fa-close"></i> Save 33% on Platinum with the Annual Plan</li>
      </ul>
      <center>
        <button type="button" class="btn4">ORDER NOW</button>
      </center>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/afelixj/vxw9r0p1/

#### Edit

Fiddle updated with below styles. Also added bootstrap css -

```
.price_wrap{
  text-align: center;
}
.price_wrap .price_block {


  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
  text-align: left;
}
.price_wrap .price_block2 {


    display: inline-block;
    float: none;
    text-align: left;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/afelixj/vxw9r0p1/1/

Comment: In where have you changed? It's right solution for me i think.

Comment: There should be some info with code rather then only code.. Please post related changes so op can get the idea.. Thanx

Comment: but it works without bootstrap's cdn!! is it right answer?

Comment: used `display:inline-block;`

Comment: @IgorIvancha i really dont know where he changed.If i know then i can try with bootstrap cdn and also can tell you is it work or not?

Comment: @afelixj but i dont want all text in center.I just want those two div in center.And this is not solve my problem :(

Comment: I agree with @Leothelion We are the learned professionals and We have a responsibility to share the knowlede and to educate the inexperienced to enable them to learn from the pool of SO knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

As you got answer but this may still be useful information for you:

As you have used a static width by using

```
.price_block{width: 37%!important;}
.price_block2{width: 37%!important;}
```

This leaves the rest of the gap to be 13%. If you want to use these static widths then by simply adding

```
.price_wrap
{
  padding-left:13%;
}
```

in your css and gap will recover and columns will be in centre.

<sup>PS: Keep in mind, if you are using float then don't forget to use `clear:both` or else you will get some white space issue or you will get trouble while tracing them in inspect element in browser.</sup>

Demo:[JSFiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/qd72ekb2/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Try giving the parent element the tag

```
padding: 0 auto;
```

Instead of the child's margin. This should fix the problem in most cases.

Comment: In which `div` will i give `padding:0 auto;` .I have tried its not working.Will you tell me specifically?

Comment: Since you want to have the divs "col-xs-6 price_block" and "col-xs-6 price_block2" you would have to give the padding to "price_wrap". Also in order to have them float next to eachother: give the first div float: left and leave the second one without a float tag. Then give them both a display: inline or display: inline-block. I believe that that should do it.

Answer (score 0):

in order to use margin: 0 auto the outer div must have a width, so use:

```
.price_wrap{
  width: 100% !important;
}
.price_block{
  margin: 0 auto !important;
}
```

[image]

Comment: I have tested this rules in the browser with developer tools when I have run the code snippet.. and it works.

Comment: need two divs `float: left each` other also.How can you do that ? Could you insert the working code in here of JSFIDDLE?

Comment: just add a div that holds the price tables and give it the `margin: 0 auto; width: 70%` and then give the price tables `display: inline-block`